# Assembly printing a simple counter

Tags: linux, assembly, printf

im new in assembly 8086 and im trying to implement a calculator in assembly.

i am required to count the number of operation received from user, and print at the end.
but every time i tried to print my variable value it prints : 134520956 instead of 1.
( i checked with gdb, I wrote: mov eax [operator_count] and 
the value of eax was 1 as required)

this is the code:

```
section .rodata
INT_FORMAT:
            DB "%d", 10, 0

section .bss
    operator_count:
             resb 10

main:
mov [operator_count], dword 0
; rest not relevant.......

inc dword [operator_count]
push operator_count                 ;push string to stuck 
push INT_FORMAT
call printf             
add esp, 4              ;remove pushed argument

;exit normaly
```

thanks for help...

edit:
it works now :)

```
inc dword [operator_count]
push dword [operator_count]                 ;push string to stuck 
push INT_FORMAT
call printf             
add esp, 8              ;remove pushed argument
```

Comment: `push operator_count` pushes the address, not the value. Try `push dword [operator_count]` instead.

Comment: lol. 
yeah it works now.

Comment: You still need to change `add esp, 4` into `add esp, 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push operator_count` pushes the address, not the value. Try `push dword [operator_count]` instead. – Jester